# Inverse of image connected component graph labeling

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, planar-graphs, image-processing

For a given image `I` one can compute connected components and define a graph structure `G` on those components. Each connected component is one node in the graph and the nodes are connected if they share a pixel boundary. This operation is for example called "connected component labeling". Let's call this `L: I -> G`.

Now assume one starts with a graph `G` with some reasonable properties. How can one compute an image `I` such that `L(I) = G`?

This "inverse" is most definitely not uniquely defined so I assume there has to be some additional constraints like a random seed. Moreover I would believe that the graph has to be at least planar for there to be a solution. Any hints on methods or algorithms would be of great help.